# How can I convert month numbers in month names?

Tags: mysql, sql, date-formatting

My table month stores numbers (1,2...,12) and I need to convert them in names (January, February...). How can I do this in my query?

```
SELECT
    id_user,
    name,
    month,
    year
FROM
    DW_RM_Log
...
```

PS: mySQL

Comment: Without knowing your RDBMS, you can do `SELECT CASE month WHEN 1 THEN 'January' WHEN 2 THEN ....` or join against a table that has that info already

Comment: I want a way without CASE, if its possible... but thanks!

Comment: then edit your question to add the RDBMS that you are using, we are not mind readers

Comment: you are right... sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) you can do

```
select date_format(str_to_date(columnName, '%m'), '%M') from tableName;
```

Note, that the `%m` and  `%M` are case sensitive. Here's how you can format dates (and how str_to_date() works: [MySQL Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server, you can do like this:

```
DECLARE @Mth smallint
SET @Mth = 11
SELECT DateName(mm,DATEADD(mm,@Mth,-1)) as [MonthName]
```

IN your case:

```
SELECT
    id_user,
    name,
    DateName(mm,DATEADD(mm,month,-1)) as [MonthName],
    year
FROM
    DW_RM_Log
```

this will return you November.

Comment: You are assuming SQL Server

Comment: Didn't know there was a DateName...awesome. I think cases are a little better though...kinda..